# what is the meaning of *.* in mysql for granting privileges?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

below is the code :

```
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP
ON *.*
TO ‘dennis’@‘localhost’;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Grant All Privileges on a Database in MySQL](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/)

> CREATING ANOTHER SUPER USER

While not particularly secure, in some cases you may wish to create another <kbd>super user</kbd>, that has **ALL privileges** across **ALL databases** on the server. That can be performed similar to above, but by replacing the database_name with the `wildcard asterisk`:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'tolkien'@'%';
```